# How to solve differential equations that look like these

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

`y' = (x +y)/(x-y)`

In my Finnish math book they classify this as a differential equation which is "reducible to equal degree". They present a way of solving this type of equation, but the explanation is really bad. I've been trying to find more information, but I just can't figure out what these are called in English. Even Wolfram Alpha doesn't know (it suggests a more general classification, "first-order nonlinear differential equation").

Does anyone know of a name for this type of differential equation? Can you direct me to a book, website or video which explains how to solve these? I'm really stuck. Any material at all would be appreciated.

Comment: These are called homogeneous equations: equations $y'=F(x,y)$ where $F$ depends only on $y/x$. There is a nice discussion of the general theory, along with your particular example, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=afZAAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&dq=differential+equation+that+depends+%22only+on+the+ratio%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY5K2Gx8rSAhVMxoMKHUJzAYsQ6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q=differential%20equation%20that%20depends%20%22only%20on%20the%20ratio%22&f=false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [first-order homogeneous differential equation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/differential-equations-homogeneous.html) since one can write it in the form:
$$y'=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
By dividing the numerator and denominator by $x$.

---

A general method to solve these is to substitute $y=v\cdot x$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}x+v$. The derivative was obtained as a result of the product rule since $v$ is a function of $x$. Then you will obtain a separable ODE.
Thus, you obtain:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y}{x-y} \implies \frac{dv}{dx}x+v=\frac{x+vx}{x-vx} \implies \frac{dv}{dx}x=\frac{1+v}{1-v}-v$$
Putting it all into one fraction gives:
$$\frac{dv}{dx}x=\frac{v^2+1}{1-v}$$
Which is separable. Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

If a function $F(x,y)$ satisfies the condition

$$ F(tx,ty)=t^nF(x,y)$$

for some $n$ it is said to be homogeneous in degree $n$ and the substitution $y=ux$ (alternately $x=uy$) will result in a separable DE in $x$ and $u$ (alternately $y$ and $u$).

There are alternate ways of doing this but I will use the method which utilizes the form

$$ M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0$$

Using your example,

\begin{equation}
(x+y)\,dx-(x-y)\,dy=0\\
\end{equation}

Let $y=ux, dy=u\,dx+x\,du$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
(x+ux)\,dx-(x-ux)(u\,dx+x\,du)&=&0\\
x(1+u^2)\,dx-x^2(1-u)\,du&=&0\\
\frac{1}{x}\,dx-\frac{1-u}{1+u^2}\,du&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
which is routine from this point. In the final answer you will replace $u$ with $\dfrac{y}{x}$ and simplify the expression if possible.